# error on formatdatetime on power automate

Tags: string, null, power-automate

i just follow this instructions how to create weekly birthday reminder using power automate : https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Weekly-Birthday-Notification-for-newbie/m-p/1723027?lightbox-message-images-1723027=503163i3A49E010C4BF961F#M190930

the problem is i got error on filter arrays that said : The template language function 'formatDateTime' expects its first parameter to be of type string. The provided value is of type 'Null'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#formatdatetime for usage details.'.

please advice

i already tried adding string type on the syntax

Comment: Have a look at your data that is going into the expression. Put simply, it must be null. Show your flow and show the resulting values that are passed in to the expression and maybe we can help.

Comment: Based on the expression and the link you shared I would say it probably is either the wrong internal column name in the expressions or an item in your birthday list has an empty birthday field. Like Skin already mentioned, please share the inputs of your failed flow run?

Comment: Hello @Skin, i use the exact same flow based on the link below but it throws an error on "Filter Array" step.

Comment: hi @Expiscornovus here are the error inputs : The execution of template action 'Filter_array' failed: The evaluation of 'query' action 'where' expression '@greaterOrEquals(formatDateTime(item()?['tgl HUT'], 'MM/dd/yyyy'), addDays(addDays(utcNow(), sub(0, dayOfWeek(utcNow()))), 8, 'MM/dd/yyyy'))' failed: 'The template language function 'formatDateTime' expects its first parameter to be of type string. The provided value is of type 'Null'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#formatdatetime for usage details.'.

Comment: It would really help if you show us data and your flow.  Honestly, very hard to actually help without it.

Comment: What Skin already mentioned, please share the data you are inputting into the array, this will help troubleshooting. This way we can see if it is an empty tgl HUT field in one of the items or if you are simply referencing the wrong field name in your expression. The data example will help with that.